# Selecting signaling protocol for video/audio app (WebRTC API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, browser, webrtc

Signaling plays an important role in WebRTC but is not standardized, allowing the developer to choose. This lack of standardization and multiple options has resulted in some confusion. A number of different signaling approaches have been proposed and used, and an understanding of the differences between the approaches is useful in selecting the right one for a given WebRTC application. So the questions arrise

- How to select a protocol for signaling between the server and end-points in a
  P2P media intensive app like video chat app?

  - `WebRTC DataChannel` vs `XMLHttpRequest`    vs `WebSockets` ? Maybe something else?
  - How and when to choose one over another?

Comment: [Here's a good article.](https://bloggeek.me/siganling-protocol-webrtc/)

Answer (score 2):

Signaling is the process of setting up a session between two parties. Because `DataChannel` depends on having a peer connection already established, you cannot use it for signaling (at least not for the initial setup). Although if you really wanted to, you could implement a `DataChannel` signaling solution to handle any *later* changes in configuration, like if one client wants to add another video stream. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022892/918910) discusses this more in-depth. Whether or not the effort involved to build and maintain this is up to you to decide.

`HTTP` and `WebSockets` will both work fine in this scenario, and I don't think one would offer any significant advantage over the other. WebSockets is technically lighter, but the signaling process is brief and doesn't involve much data transfer.

I'd recommend using something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which abstracts away the differences between the two protocols and automatically handles upgrading and downgrading.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Got rid of it :)

Comment: I thought the idea of using a WebRTC Data Channel for signaling didn't make any sense at all either, but [this page](https://bloggeek.me/siganling-protocol-webrtc/) claims it's possible after establishing the "initial connection."

Comment: Yeah, that page's answer is a little confusing and maybe out dated.  You definitely first need a webRTC peer connection for data channels.  He might have meant that, after you setup a peer connection, you can use data channels to modify or add streams or create additional peer connections with the same peer.

Comment: Switching to datachannels for signaling after initial negotiation is doable. See demo in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30022892/918910).

Comment: @jib Thanks for pointing that out, and I've edited my answer accordingly. There are definitely some scenarios where a separate DataChannel signaling solution might be useful, but it's a lot more time and effort spent for relatively little gain.

Comment: If you want snappy configuration changes during a call, then it's hard to beat data channels. Their design is a shoe-in for web-sockets, so if you're already using web-sockets for signaling, then switchover is just an assignment. I don't know why anyone would *not* do this for anything but the simplest call. The only reason this wasn't baked into RTCPeerConnection itself was the argument that the API should be put at the most fundamental level.