# In webRTC,When the sdp exchange is completed, is the role of websocket finished?

Tags: webrtc

As far as I know, the role of the signaling server is to exchange sdp between the web browsers you want to communicate with.

I understood the process as follows.

1. Web browser passes sdp to signaling server through websocket
2. The server passes each other's sdp back to the web browsers.
3. When the transfer is complete, close the web socket.
4. After that, web browsers can communicate with each other without a signaling server

Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you are using vanilla or trickle ICE.

In trickle ICE, ICE candidates are not discovered via STUN, for example, prior to sending the SDP. In this case your webRTC endpoints may not be able to communicate because they will not be able to communicate with each other yet. The signaling layer is still required to relay the ICE candidates to establish the peer connection. Once the peer connection is established, signaling is no longer required. Most implementations I have seen use trickle ICE because it usually reduces the latency to establish the peer connection.

In vanilla ICE, the ICE candidates are discovered prior to sending the SDP. In this case, the signaling is complete after sending the SDP.

Comment: Right. Also, you'll still need the signaling channel if you want to [add media during a call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30022892/918910), unless you [set up a data channel for signaling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30016613/918910). The risk of using data channel for signaling is it won't save you if ICE (network) failure causes you to need an ICE restart.